# TextInput Enter Space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing React native app. Using TextInput for First Name or Last name. TextInput empty when enter space button on text input on empty textInput box. Then I will check textInput in Empty or not. He is showing some value on textInput. But I do not have enter any value on textinput or only enter space. I think he count space as a character. So please help me to check this condition.

```
 <TextInput 
                                        placeholder="Joe" 
                                        autoFocus={false} 
                                        returnKeyType={"next"} 
                                        blurOnSubmit={false}
                                        onChangeText={firstName => this.setState({ firstName })}
                                        onSubmitEditing={(event) => {this.passTextInput1.focus()}}
                                        style={styles.textBox1} />
                                    <TextInput
                                        placeholder="Bloggs" 
                                        inputRef={(input) => {this.passTextInput1 = input}}
                                        returnKeyType={"next"}
                                        onChangeText={lastName => this.setState({ lastName })}
                                        onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.onValidations()}
                                        style={styles.textBox2} />


    Condition:
    if(this.state.firstName == '' && this.state.lastName == ''){
                  Alert.alert('Please fill the required fields')
              } else if(this.state.firstName == '') {
                  Alert.alert('Please fill the First Name')
              } else if(this.state.lastName == '') {
                  Alert.alert('Please fill the Last Name')
              } else {

                    this.props.navigation.navigate('AccountStep2', {
                        Firstname: this.state.firstName,
                        Lastname: this.state.lastName,
                      })
              }




    Textinput Check empty or not. when textInput is empty. when click on space button. than check condition he show some value on textinput
```

Comment: you can use the trim function.  if(this.state.firstName.trim() == '')

Answer (score 1):

The functions Trim can delete space.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/trim